# Пропускаю первый элемент в цикле, не могу понять как правильно это решить

Tags: c#, for

```cs
public static List<int> gradingStudents(List<int> grades){
List<int> finaGrades = new List<int>(grades);
for(int i = 0; i < finaGrades.Count; i++){
    if(finaGrades[i] % 5 != 0 ){
        finaGrades[i] += 1;
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Мне необходимо округлить числа, и все работает, кроме первого элемента

Comment: Что значит "округлить" в вашем понимании? Вы тут что делаете: если число не делится на цело на 5, вы добавляете к нему 1 и начинаете цикл заново. Но при этом в начале следующего цикла срабатывает `i++`, поэтому цикл начинается с `i = 1`, а не с `i = 0`. Вообще, если вы "вручную" меняете переменную цикла, то лучше не использовать стандартную конструкцию `for`, иначе это путаница сплошная. Используйте `while` какой-нибудь или как-то ещё уйдите от стандартного `for`, он тут всё только путает. Ну или просто уберите `i++` из `for` и прибавляйте внутри цикла если нужно.

Comment: `i = 0;` заменить на `i = -1;`, чтобы последующий `i++` цикла дал `0`.

Comment: Я просто тренируюсь писать алгоритмы и таки глупые ошибки делаю, но по итогу как я понял я выбрал не самый уместный способ решить данную задачку

Comment: Суть задачи заключалась в том, что мне нужно было написать метод который бы округлял некоторые оценки студентов, а некоторые оставлял нетронутыми. И для этого я решил заполнить новый лист с округленными значениями всех данных входящего в мой метод списка. После мне бы уже было легче проводить операцию сравнения 2х разных списков

Comment: Округлить в плане, чтобы данные стали кратны 5. То есть делились на 5 без остатка.

Answer (score 0):

Первый элемент вы проскакиваете, потому что в начале каждого цикла срабатывает `i++`. Да и вообще я не понимаю, зачем вам каждый раз возвращаться к нулевому элементу, ведь вы его уже округлили до того, возможно. Зачем с 1000-го элемента опять возвращаться к нулевому? Зачем с миллионого возвращаться к нулевому? Округлили элемент - идёте дальше. Возвращаться не нужно. Само округление можно сделать без цикла, просто посчитав, сколько нужно добавить для того, чтобы делилось на 5. И тогда цикл ломать не нужно:

```cs
List<int> finaGrades = new List<int>(grades);
for(int i = 0; i < finaGrades.Count; i++){
    if(finaGrades[i] % 5 != 0 ){
        finaGrades[i] += 5 - finaGrades[i] % 5;
    }
}
```

P.S. Исправил показ картинки в вопросе. Что-то я не понимаю - откуда берутся 67 и 33, что-то я не понимаю вообще тогда эту задачу. Приложите условие задачи к вопросу.

Comment: `в начале каждого цикла срабатывает i++` в конце итерации инкремент происходит, а не в начале.

Comment: `finaGrades[i] += 5 - finaGrades[i] % 5;` ошибка, что если `finaGrades[i] % 5` вернет `0`?